# CSS Wordpress Blog on Iphone

Tags: iphone, css, wordpress

I am working on this wordpress blog http://www.taranmarlowjewelry.com/?page_id=7 (looks fine on a normal web broswer) I tried to edit the CSS so it looks good on an iphone...I added these lines in my iphone css file

```
.wrapper{
    position:relative;
    width:840px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.blog #page{
    width:840px !important;
}

.blog #main{
    width:840px !important;
}

.blog #primary {
    width:220px !important;
}

.blog #content {
    width: 220px !important;
}

.blog #secondary {
    width:200px !important;
    float:right !important;
}
```

but there is a massive space between the blog and the sidebar and the width of this page is too wide, while my home, about page look good with the .wrapper at a width of 840px;

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Wow those are a lot of `!important` keywords! Try to use them sparingly...

Comment: nope that didn't do anything :( but thanks TheZ

Comment: It isn't a solution to your problem, just a comment on your style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using initial scale?

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Add that in and adjust your CSS accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to use a responsive theme, so you'd be including a base.css stylesheet for all frame-formats and then adding style sheets for each new frame-format. Something like:

http://yourdomain.com/library/css/style.css' type='text/css' media='(min-width:481px)' />

Then you can use functions within that stylesheet to apply more styles to larger frame-formats. Bones Theme (by themble) is a great place to start learning about responsive web design.

Failing that - Sean is right, start with the meta viewport settings and adjust from there. There's a great answer on iPad and iPhone screen sizes here [iPad browser WIDTH & HEIGHT standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375706/ipad-browser-width-height-standard)

Andy