# How to fit to screen after changing viewport width on orientation change?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, tablet

I need the viewport width for a page to be 950px in landscape and 630px in portrait. These pixel widths are unfortunately inflexible.

I'm adjusting the width of the DOM content based on orientation using CSS media queries.

I'm listening for orientation change events in JS to resize the viewport on orientation change.

Everything looks good on initial page load (portrait or landscape).

However, after an orientation change, Mobile Safari preserves the previous scale setting, instead of fitting the viewport to the screen. A double-tap or two straightens it out. But I need that to be automatic.

I've attached the source below, and uploaded it to a demo [URL](http://adamflorin.com/xfer/stackoverflow/ios-orientation/).

Below are screen captures taken after orientation changes: from landscape to portrait, and from portrait to landscape.

How can I force Safari to automatically set the viewport width to the screen width? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Changing the various scale settings in the viewport have not helped. Setting `maximum-scale=1.0` or `initial-scale=1.0` appears to override my `width`, setting `width` to `device-width` (i.e. 1024 or 768 on my iPad 2), leaving dead margin space. Setting `minimum-scale=1.0` appears to do nothing.

[image: From landscape to portrait]

[image: From portrait to landscape]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>iPad orientation</title>

      <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes">

      <script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">;
        /**
        * update viewport width on orientation change
        */
        function adapt_to_orientation() {
          // determine new screen_width
          var screen_width;
          if (window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 180) {
            // portrait
            screen_width = 630;
          } else if (window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90) {
            // landscape
            screen_width = 950;
          }

          // resize meta viewport
          $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', 'width='+screen_width);
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {

          // bind to handler
          $('body').bind('orientationchange', adapt_to_orientation);

          // call now
          adapt_to_orientation();
        });

      </script>
      <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body {
          margin: 0;
        }
        #block {
          background-color: #333;
          color: #fff;
          font-size: 128px;

          /* landscape */
          width: 950px;
        }
        #block .right {
          float: right
        }
        @media only screen and (orientation:portrait) {
          #block {
            width: 630px;
          }
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="block">
        <div class="right">&rarr;</div>
        <div class="left">&larr;</div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem and wrote some JavaScript to fix it. I put it on Github here:

https://github.com/incompl/ios-reorient

Here is the code for your convenience:

```
window.document.addEventListener('orientationchange', function() {
  var iOS = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g);
  var viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
  if (iOS && viewportmeta) {
    if (viewportmeta.content.match(/width=device-width/)) {
      viewportmeta.content = viewportmeta.content.replace(/width=[^,]+/, 'width=1');
    }
    viewportmeta.content = viewportmeta.content.replace(/width=[^,]+/, 'width=' + window.innerWidth);
  }
  // If you want to hide the address bar on orientation change, uncomment the next line
  // window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}, false);
```

Comment: iOS now ignores these properties.

Answer (score 8):

OK, the answer lay in the `*-scale` attributes after all.

You can force a specific scale by setting both `maximum-scale` and `minimum-scale` to the same value. But you have to sacrifice user scaling by setting the meta tag to `<meta name='viewport' content='user-scalable=no' />`.

Note that the `*-scale` settings are relative to the device's screen dimensions—which vary from device to device. Fortunately you can look these up in the `screen` object in JS.

So, if your content width is under 980, your forced scale should be `screen_dimension / content_width`.

This updated version of my above JS has made orientation changes work smoothly. Tested on iPhone 4 and iPad 2.

```
    function adapt_to_orientation() {
      var content_width, screen_dimension;

      if (window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 180) {
        // portrait
        content_width = 630;
        screen_dimension = screen.width * 0.98; // fudge factor was necessary in my case
      } else if (window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90) {
        // landscape
        content_width = 950;
        screen_dimension = screen.height;
      }

      var viewport_scale = screen_dimension / content_width;

      // resize viewport
      $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content',
        'width=' + content_width + ',' +
        'minimum-scale=' + viewport_scale + ', maximum-scale=' + viewport_scale);
    }
```

Comment: I too can confirm the above has wonderful results on an ipad (May 2013)

Comment: Obviously screws up the width on many other devices. So not really a good solution. But there is finally something to work with :-)

Answer (score 3):

use the wisdom of this post and simply get the width and height of the container of your script (window width&height)...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9049670/818732

using this viewport: `target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no` solved my problems on android AND ios. Note that target-densitydpi will be flagged on ALL other devices but Android but won't do any harm. It'll make sure nothing is scaled automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem with iOS, after some testing ended up with a solution you can find here

[Reset Zoom on iOS after viewport width change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420584/reset-zoom-on-ios-after-viewport-width-change)

In my solution zoom is disabled but you can freely remove "user-scalable=no" to make it zoomable.