# Reset Zoom on iOS after viewport width change

Tags: ios, css, html

we are making an HTML5 app where width is not know at design time.
So we change the viewport tag at runtime to match the desidered size.

e.g.

```
<meta name="viewport" id="viewport-meta" content="width=' + params.mobilePortraitWidth + ', initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

The problem on iOS is that after we change the viewport size, view is not correctly scaled until we double tap the screen.

EDIT, after double tap is all fine, so: how can we "DOUBLE TAP" programmatically?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your replies, I would like to share the solution we found after some test on iPhone 5s with iOS 9.2 and iPad Air with iOS 8.4.

Basically, to make it work, we didn't set initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no

Following a working example

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" id="viewport-meta" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
    <style>
        html, body { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
        h1 { padding: 1em; background-color: #FF80BB; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>I am the page content</h1>
    <button id="s320">Set 320</button><br />
    <button id="s640">Set 640</button><br />
    <button id="s960">Set 960</button>
    <script>
        function setViewportWidth(newWidth) {
          var m = document.getElementById("viewport-meta");
          m.setAttribute('content', 'width=' + newWidth + ', user-scalable=no');
        }
        document.getElementById("s320").onclick = function () { return setViewportWidth(320); };
        document.getElementById("s640").onclick = function () { return setViewportWidth(640); };
        document.getElementById("s960").onclick = function () { return setViewportWidth(960); };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *js = @"var t=document.createElement('meta'); t.name="viewport"; t.content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=3.0"; document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(t);";
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```

EDIT
Thanks for update.
I had very similar issue and remember that setting viewport meta tag solved it.
 
If you are trying to modify this meta tag just after loading html, try doing that in `webViewDidFinishLoad` (`loadRequest` is asynchronous).

Another solution would be to read your html file into `NSString` and replace that meta tag before loading it to webView.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi scope thank you for your code, I've changed the answer cause I had explained it bad, I don't need to change viewport dinamically (already do), I need to set the scale or zoom level of the safari view to fit my content because iOS is the only os that don't reset it automatically. After a double tap on the screen it get ok so I would like to replicate this behaviour.