# what is the ipad mini browser width/height?

Tags: ipad, viewport, ipad-mini

I did a bunch of googling but I can't seem to find the (non-retina) html width/height for the ipad mini.

More specifically, the width/height when using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1">
```

Would be great if someone can post a link or provide details similar to this excellent answer:

[iPad browser WIDTH & HEIGHT standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375706/ipad-browser-width-height-standard)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It will be the same as for the iPad, they run at the same resolution and scale.

So, from the answer you linked to, it would be:

- Portrait: 768x946
- Landscape: 1024x690

Comment: Are you sure? Since the screen is smaller it seems a little illogical that the both the ipad and the mini can both have 1024px width (in landscape) considering the screen widths are very different.

Comment: @Joe Yeah, all the elements on the iPad mini are a little bit smaller than the iPad. The mini has more PPI. See http://www.apple.com/ipad-mini/specs/ as it states the resolution: "1024-by-768 resolution at 163 pixels per inch (ppi)"

Comment: @Joe physically smaller pixels.

Comment: Yes, had to wait for X time to pass before accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

1024-by-768 resolution according to apple

http://www.apple.com/ipad-mini/design/

Comment: That's not quite the same as the width and height for the browser, the browser has elements on screen that shrinks it a bit.