# Bootstrap and Ipad Portrait

Tags: css, ipad

I use twitter bootstrap as my CSS template.

My responsive design works everywhere (android phone, android tablet, iphone, computer) besides on the IPad.

I included the viewport meta tag in the head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

as described here:
[CSS Media Query max-width and ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345839/css-media-query-max-width-and-ipad)

I alert the viewport width:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($(window).width());
});
```

And it gives me:
768 in Portrait and 1024 in landscape for the ipad.

I target the css in my media queries with:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
```

like described here:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/
Which also seems to work.

But the bootstrap columns don't go with the IPad. E.g.

```
col-xs-12 col-sm-6
```

stays in the medium view. But according to the documentation `$screen-sm: 768px !default;` it should break at 768px.

The workaround I did is so far:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
    div.container>div.row>div {
        width:100%;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
... and a lot more resets ...
}
```

I found this but it is from 2012:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/2155

**Question:**
Why does it behave like that and is there a **good way** to solve it with css? I think the one I used is not very practical. Or is the only way to use sass/less and redefine the vars?

Comment: Have you tried playing with the variables in SASS, did you find a solution?