# mobile-safari ignoring media query

Tags: css, cross-browser, media-queries, mobile-safari

[Here's](http://www.izzas-skin-care.com)  my almost finished website.

The following media query is ignored by my iPad mini's browser. Why?

```
@media all and (max-width:800px){
#trigger {display:none;}
#telephone_leaf {display:none;}
#number_leaf {opacity:1;}
}
```

(style.css, line 974)

It works when resizing the desktop browser!

Actually, this is part of another problem. I can't seem to get the telephone-hover/click-leaf image to work on my iPad. For that reason, I'm trying to degrade into just showing the god-damn telephone number from the start at a certain browser width. But not even the @m works!! Going crazy.

Comment: Look here [Link][1] this should answer your question


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375706/ipad-browser-width-height-standard

Answer (score 2):

I just found the answer! max-width is not supported by mobile devices. You have to put it as max-device-width! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to prefix all your code!
`@media` is still new to CSS3, so make sure it's all prefixed!

So with your code it needs to be like this:

```
@-webkit-media all and (max-width:800px){
#trigger {display:none;}
#telephone_leaf {display:none;}
#number_leaf {opacity:1;}
}
```

Comment: ah I thought @media is universal! Or do you mean the CSS inside the media query?

Comment: the only thing I'm using in that @media is opacity, but opacity only needs a IE filter workaround and the problem occurs on mobile Safari...

Comment: @NilsSens What I mean is this: `@-webkit-media (blah) {}`

Comment: @NilsSens Please put my answer as the correct one. Thanks!

Comment: Checking if it solves the problem right now. Will do!

Comment: Sorry it didn't solve the problem... still only the telephone image loads. #telephone_leaf {display:none;} is completely ignored.

Comment: Put -> `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` inside your head tags! Does it work?

Comment: I tried it, also tried <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" /> -  nada

Comment: I just found the answer! max-width is not supported by mobile devices. You have to put it as max-device-width! :)